# where the function init() in the class yii\base\application is called? Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function init()
{
    $this->state = self::STATE_INIT;
    $this->bootstrap();
}
```

where the function `init()` in the class **yii\base\application** is called?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-object.html#init()-detail):

> This method is invoked at the end of the constructor after the object is initialized with the given configuration.

Furthermore, from [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-components.html):

> You may override this method to perform sanity checks and normalization of the properties.